# $U,W$ are sub-spaces of $R^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given $U,W$  are sub-spaces of $R^4$.Also ,$dim(U \cap W^\bot) \ge 2$ ,and $(1,1,0,0),(0,0,1,1) \in U$ and $(1,0,0,0),(0,0,0,1) \in W$

Find bases for $W,W^\bot,U$.

Well, because $W$ is a subspace of $V$, I know that $W = Sp\{(1,0,0,0),(0,0,0,1)\}$ those 2 vectors are linearly independent and they span $W$, so they are a base of W. also $dimW = 2$

From here, the same for $U$, which means base for $U$ would be: $U = Sp\{(1,1,0,0),(0,0,1,1)\}$ and $dimU = 2$.

from here I need somehow to find $W^\bot$, I believe that it's somehow got to do with $dim(U \cap W) \ge 2$. cuz $dim(U + W^\bot)= 2+ 2+dim(U \cap W^\bot) \ge 2$ , but I still don't know how it helps me. I believe it is because $W^\bot = Sp\{W^\bot\}$ and somehow to continue from here.

Comment: If you consider $U = \mathrm{span}\{(1,1,0,0),(0,0,1,1)\}$ and $W = \mathrm{span}\{(1,0,0,0),(0,0,0,1)\}$ then $U\cap W=\{0\}.$

Comment: I know that $e1,e4$ span W, I believe, then: $e2,e3$ should span the $W^\bot$. but I want to prove it somehow algebrically.

Comment: I meant: $dim(U \cap W^\bot) \ge 2$ @mfl

Comment: Since $e_2,e_3\in W^{\perp}$ and $\dim W^{\perp}= 2$ you are right, $e_2,e_3$ span $W^{\perp}.$

Comment: but how can I prove it in another way? I mean, if I put the base of W in a matrix, how can I find $W^\bot$ and not just by guessing like I did now?

Comment: Use that $\dim W^{\perp}\ge \dim(U\cap W^{\perp})\ge 2$ and $\dim W\ge 2\implies \dim W^{\perp}\le 2.$

Comment: and $dimW + dimW^\bot = dimR^4$ so $dimW^\bot = 2$

Comment: and from here, I can deduce that if$ W = Sp\{e_2,e_3\}$ , then I must find 2 vectors that will make W and the other 2 vectors that I "added" a base for $R^4$, which must be in this case - $e_1,e_4$

Comment: or any span of $e_1,e_4$